# Autohotkey-COM-Youtube : How get channel id from url?

Tags: autohotkey

**I can get the video name using this code.
But to get the channel id I change the "title" to "channel_id" but it doesn't work...
I want to get channel id instead of title**

```
MsgBox, % YouTubeTitle("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzL0OBjnK8o")
return

YouTubeTitle(url) {
    hObject := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    hObject.Open("GET", url)
    hObject.Send()
    RegExMatch(hObject.ResponseText, "(?<=title>).*?(?= - YouTube</title>)", title)
    return title
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the channel ID:

```
MsgBox, % YouTubeChannelId("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzL0OBjnK8o")
return

YouTubeChannelId(url) {
    hObject := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    hObject.Open("GET", url)
    hObject.Send()
    RegExMatch(hObject.ResponseText, "itemprop=""author"".+?channel\/([^""]+)", ChannelId)
    return ChannelId1
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great :)